# What will happen if I remove this line from /etc/hosts

Tags: networking

I am trying to configure Hadoop and have problems configuring it. One doubt I have about network config and it's related to host info.

In `/etc/hosts` second line is like `127.0.1.1  slave1-machine` and I know it is related to machine name. But the thing I do not know, is that what is the purpose for this line and if I remove it from the file, what will happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you remove the line you can't resolve the hostname slave1-machine to a IP Address anymore.
Linux looks into the /etc/hosts before triyng to resolve a hostname via a DNS Query.
So if you remove the Line. Linux tries to resolve the hostname slave1-machine via DNS and get a negative response.

Answer (score 3):

The range 127/8 (which includes 127.0.1.1) is bound to your loopback interface. Usually 127.0.1.1 is the IP that resolves your computer hostname.

If you remove that line slave1-machine won't be able to resolve. (Its not a big problem. Some times it will throw an error saying hostname can't be resolved.)